# Deleting partial rows conditionally in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

Dear postgresql gurus,

I am stuck with this interesting requirement in SQL.

```
Table : EmpBonus
id               long,
empid            long,
bonuspaid        date,
paidby           string
```

bonus may be paid every year. The paidby column can have one of these two values (userA, userB).

I have to fulfill the below two requirements using SQL queries and no Stored Procedure or Functions

- If an employee has been paid bonus by userA and userB both, delete all entries where bonus was paid by userB
- If an employee has been paid bonus by userB only, then delete all entries except the first one.

I tried using two common table expressions,

- one to select all the empids where the number of rows for the mpid is > 1
- two to select all the empids where the bonus was not paid by userB
- joining these two with the original table, on empid gives me a list of rows which I can possibly use for deleting what I need. But I am stuck at this point.

Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT**

This is a copy of the answer with a little modification

```
SELECT eb.id, eb.empId, eb.bonuspaid, eb.paidby, eb2.seqnum, eb2.a_paid 
FROM empbonus eb
JOIN (SELECT eb2.*
      ,COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE paidby = 'A') OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS a_paid
      ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
      FROM empbonus eb2
     ) eb2
ON eb.id = eb2.id
WHERE ( 
         (eb2.a_paid > 0 AND eb.paidby = 'B') OR
         (eb2.a_paid = 0 AND eb.paidby = 'B' AND seqnum > 1)
      )
ORDER BY eb.empId, eb.id ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can use a subquery to calculate the additional information you need.  Then you can "join" this in in the `delete`:

```
delete empbonus eb
    from (select eb2.*,
                 count(*) filter (where paidby = 'A') over (partition by empid) as a_paid,
                 row_number() over (partition by empid, b_paid order by id) as seqnum
          from empbonus eb2
         ) eb2
    where eb.id = eb2.id and
          ( (eb2.a_paid > 0 and eb.paidby = 'B') or
            (eb2.a_paid = 0 and eb.paidby = 'B' and seqnum = 1)
          );
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I had to make some changes but it works I believe. Couldn't verify all the records as there are like a 100,000 records in the table and around 2200 qualify for deletion. Could you check my edit which is a copy and slight modification of your query.

Comment: @dharam . . . If you only have As and Bs then your edit looks fine.